# How to change the jquery ui dialog button color?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I need to change the color of jquery ui dialog button color by adding a class of another css.

```
  $('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').find('button').addClass('cancelButton');
```

The above line of code has been used to change the css class but it doesnt help to change the color.

A sample code has been placed in the following fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/DOmEl/PCkQD/5/

Can anyone help me to identify what is the issue here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$('#message1').find('.ui-button').addClass('cancelButton');
```

and

```
.ui-button.cancelButton {
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa
    /*{borderColorContent}*/
    ;
    color: #FF0000
    /*{fcContent}*/
    ;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/AvF8V/)

Comment: How i can achieve this without using .ui-button extension like below? EG: .cancelButton {
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa
    /*{borderColorContent}*/
    ;
    color: #FF0000
    /*{fcContent}*/
    ;
}because I need to refer class which is already existing my application. (i dont want to change the structure of that css)

Comment: when i remove the .ui-button and add the line   background: red !important; to your css its working. Can you please explain how? http://jsfiddle.net/DOmEl/AvF8V/2/

Answer (score 6):

You can also set the class of a button when initialising the buttons collection:

```
buttons: [ { text: 'Cancel', class : 'cancelButton' } ]
```

Answer (score 4):

Gruff Bunny is right, but the code is very simple. 
More useful code can look like:

```
$('#dialog').html("This is a confirmation dialog.");
$('#dialog').dialog({
            buttons : [
                {
                    text:'OK',
                    class:'green',
                    click: function() {
                        alert("OK");
                        $(this).dialog("close");                        
                    }                   
                },
                {
                    text:'CANCEL',
                    class:'red',
                    click: function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }                   
                }
            ]
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

The jquery-ui buttons are not html buttons. They are constructed using divs and spans. Thus you need to find it by other means, like class or id:

```
$('#btnCancel').addClass('cancelButton');
```

See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PCkQD/7/)

#### Edit

If you want to change multiple buttons then either find or add common class, like in ArunPJohny's answer. All ui buttons already have the `ui-button` class, and this is enough in some cases.

Comment: so if i need to change two buttons, is there any simple way by finding out all the buttons and change the color? $("#message1").find('button').addClass('cancelButton'); I tried the above but not working.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#dialog').html("This is a confirmation dialog.");
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
    buttons: [
        {
            text: "OK",
            open: function() {
                $(this).addClass('okClass');
            },
            click: function() {
                alert("OK");
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        },
        {
            text: "CANCEL",
            open: function() {
                $(this).addClass('cancelClass');
            },
            click: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO Mduja. It will be great if you can add some descriptive info in one or two lines regarding your answer to understand it better for all SO users and will help the community. Thanks.