# How to change the jquery ui dialog button/background color using API?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

I am using the jquery ui dialog. I have looked at [How to change the jquery ui dialog button color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19079021/how-to-change-the-jquery-ui-dialog-button-color) but it looks they this user is taking a different approach.

I am using the dialog `buttons` option.

Here is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#credentialsDialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        buttons: {
            Submit: function() {
              $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        },
        dialogClass: 'ui-dialog-titlebar'
    });
    $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
        $("#credentialsDialog").dialog('open');
    });
});
```

Here is the CSS it is referring to:

```
.ui-dialog-titlebar {
  background-color: #f6f6ff;
  background-image: none;
  color: #f6f6ff;
}
```

I have also tried this [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19693722/jquery-ui-change-the-button-class):

```
buttons: {
            Submit: function() {
              $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            },
            'class': 'ui-dialog-titlebar'
        }
```

But this is not working either.

**What is the correct way to change the background color of the button area?**

Here is my dialog so far:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to style the buttons, target them with:

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane button.ui-button {
/* your rules here */
}
```

Comment: so the `.ui-dialog-buttonpane` will change the background color, correct?

Comment: `.ui-dialog-buttonpane` is the class attached to the div that the buttons reside in. You want to use that class to make sure your rules are more specific than the default CSS.